# Zeppelin Docker Interpreter Configuration

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

I have created a Zeppelin docker image in my local system and configured the Spark Interpreter through maven repositories and runned the Zeppelin It worked. But when I stop the Docker and runned again the Interpreter binding was gone. How to solve this Issue ? I want that Interpreter binding one-time so that when ever I stop the docker and run again It has to store those interpreter Binding as it is.

Answer (score 6):

You need 3 volumes for persisting configurations, notebooks and logs.
**Note:** If you added custom interpreters, you need an additional volume for your interpreter binaries.

```
docker volume create zeppelin-conf
docker volume create zeppelin-notebook
docker volume create zeppelin-logs
docker volume create zeppelin-interpreter
```

Run the container with above volumes mounted.

```
docker run -d --restart always -p 8080:8080 -v zeppelin-conf:/zeppelin/conf -v zeppelin-notebook:/zeppelin/notebook -v zeppelin-logs:/zeppelin/logs -v zeppelin-interpreter:/zeppelin/interpreter apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
```

If you just want to persist configurations you can use following lines:

```
docker volume create zeppelin-conf
docker run -d --restart always -p 8080:8080 -v zeppelin-conf:/zeppelin/conf apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
```

Configurations:`/zeppelin/conf`
Notebooks: `/zeppelin/notebook`
Logs: `/zeppelin/logs`
Interpreters: `/zeppelin/interpreter`

**Edit:** The **/zeppelin** directory is the default home directory for docker images. See [Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/c46f55f1d81df944fd1b69a7ccb68d0647294543/scripts/docker/zeppelin/bin/Dockerfile#L22). Therefore, you don't need to specify ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR, ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR or ZEPPELIN_INTERPRETER_DIR environment variables.

Comment: You need to also set environment variables to tell it to use those volumes: -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/zeppelin/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='zeppelin/notebook'

Comment: Nope, environment variables are not needed. See my edit please.

Comment: With Zeppelin 0.10.1 you need to prepend /opt to all paths

Answer (score 3):

Mount file into docker run is easy - just pass it into [--volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) parameter. But in zeppelin case there some parameters pre-configured there, so replace it with empty file is most likely is not what you want achieve. So I could recommend first get that file with default content from container and then mount to it in next run. Please follow step-by step instructions:

1. First we prepare default config for nest runs.

   1. Run default container **temporary**:

      ```sh
      sudo docker run -d --name zeppelin-test apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
      ```
   2. And get default config from it:

      ```
      mkdir -p conf
      sudo docker zeppelin-test cat /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json > conf/interpreter.json
      ```

   > **Note 1**: It will not be used for work, so most parameters unimportant. It need to be done once for setup only!
   >
   > **Note 2**: Because that config populated on start unfortunately you can't obtain it on single run like: `sudo docker run --rm apache/zeppelin:0.8.1 cat /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`
2. Now we can provide use it as bind-mount.

   1. If you use direct docker run method without [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), add option, among others: `--volume $(pwd)/conf/interpreter.json:/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`
   2. But I recommend use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), so there option placed under `volumes:` key like `- ./conf/interpreter.json:/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`. Full example:

      ```yaml
      version: '3.7'

      services:
        zeppelin:
          image: apache/zeppelin:0.8.1
          ports:
            - "7077:7077"
            - "8080:8080"
          volumes:
            - ./logs:/logs
            - ./notebook:/notebook
            - ./conf/interpreter.json:/zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json
          environment:
            ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR: /notebook
            ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR: /logs
      ```

      And then just run from that directory:

      ```
      docker-compose up -d
      ```

Comment: Zeppelin configs are now stored under /opt/zeppelin/conf.

Comment: `sudo docker run --rm apache/zeppelin:0.8.1 cat /zeppelin/conf/interpreter.json`
you should add `exec` after docker. And sudo is not mandatory.

Comment: Sudo required if you run under regular user and use `docker`, not said rootless `podman`

Answer (score 0):

Interpreter bindings are stored in `conf/interpreter.json`. Need use external `interpreter.json` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have understood but can you tell me how to link external interpreter.json.

Comment: @Pragna please search elsewhere for Docker volume management and linking host files into containers